# making a fixed yet transparent footer that the body block doesn't cover when scrolling down (bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have read through some bootstrap to make a fixed header/footer, and they work. But, the body (the white block) is bleeding through my header. I want something more complicated then the examples I've seen, where the footer is transparent so you can see the background, but buttons are above the background of course, and the body is in a central rectangle that you can scroll down, but it doesn't cover the footer up.

I'm having issues getting the background pic on jsfiddle. The picture below is the very bottom of my page. I just want that bottom part with the 4 buttons Home, .., .., Articles to be background. I already made the footer like this:

```
footer {
    position: fixed;
    height: 100px;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background:transparent;
    z-index:999;

}
```

I call the image as such:

```
    html {
        background-image:url('/media/images/bookshelf_background.jpg');
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        background-size:100%;
    }
```

I changed the body slightly on this page, just inline, as:

`<body style="width:76%; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;">`

The footer looks like this:

```
    ...
        <footer class="footer">
          <div  class="container">
              <div style="padding-top:16px;" class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
                  {% block buttons %}
                      <a href="{% url 'index:silo' %}"><p class="footer_button">Home</p></a>
                      <a href="{% url 'index:new-article' %}"><p class="footer_button">Add new articles</p></a>
                      <a href="{% url 'index:manage-tags' %}"><p class="footer_button">Manage tags</p></a>
                      <a href="{% url 'index:archives-list' %}"><p class="footer_button">Archives</p></a>
                  {% endblock %}
              </div>
          </div>
        </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

I don't want to give background pic a huge z-index either as it may cover the body. But if I set footer to a huge z-index and made it transparent, I'm confused to why body still covers the background as I scroll down. How can I enclose body in a rectangle of the background where body doesn't cover up my footer? Thank you

[image]